# How to total values in another Activity?

Tags: android

i need to sum the values in the second activity.  I can not get it to total correctly. would someone be kind enough to help me?

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etwalkingburned);
final EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etrunningburned);
mcardiototalbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cardiototalbutton);
mcardiototalbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int walkingburned = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            int runningburned = Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TotalActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("CardioTotal",walkingburned);
            myIntent.putExtra("CardioTotal",runningburned);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

public class TotalActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.totalactivity);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int walkingburned = extras.getInt("CardioTotal");
    int runningburned = extras.getInt("CardioTotal");
    int cardiototal = walkingburned + runningburned;

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cardiototalresult);

    walkingburned = walkingburned + 0;
    runningburned = runningburned + 0;
    cardiototal = walkingburned + runningburned;

    tv.setText("Cals.:" + cardiototal);
}
```

Comment: Set the inputtype of those edittext as number. Add them in the activity you are getting them and send the sum to the next activity

Comment: You're using "CardioTotal" twice as a key when putting your values into the Intent extras. Use different keys.

Comment: Also I just noticed you are using `getApplicationContext()` in the `onClick(...)` method of your first `Activity`. An application `Context` can only be used to start an `Activity` in certain cases (see the Context Capabilities in this article - http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/ ). Instead, use the `Context` of the first `Activity`, e.g., `MyActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are putting and getting extras to/from your intent.

```
myIntent.putExtra("CardioTotal",walkingburned);
myIntent.putExtra("CardioTotal",runningburned);
```

Think of an extra as a key-value pair. You should have a different string as the first parameter each time you call `putExtra`, otherwise you will overwrite the value of what you've already put in. So basically you put in the `walkingburned` value and then overwrote it with the `runningburned` value because you used the same key string.

Likewise, in your second activity you need to reference the values by their unique string "key" or you will just get the same value two times.

In this situation, there is more than one way to skin a cat. More specifically, you could do the addition in your first activity and only store one extra (the sum) to avoid the confusion of multiple extras. But, I think it would benefit you more to understand how extras and intents works.

For starters, instead of using `"CardioTotal"`for each extra, you can simply call the string something similar to your variable name. This is what I do and it would make your code easier to understand in my opinion.

```
myIntent.putExtra("Walking Burned",walkingburned);
myIntent.putExtra("Running Burned",runningburned);
```

It doesn't really matter what String you put in the first parameter as long as you know that they are supposed to represent different values.

The second change you would then need to make is how you get the extra out of the intent.

```
int walkingburned = extras.getInt("CardioTotal");
int runningburned = extras.getInt("CardioTotal");
```

What you are currently doing is retrieving the same value (you are using the same key string therefore it is the same value) to two separate variables. So the value you would be seeing is double the `runningburned` value.

Now, since you have two different Strings for the two different variables in your intent, you can just say:

```
int walkingburned = extras.getInt("Walking Burned");
int runningburned = extras.getInt("Running Burned");
```

The rest of your code is fine.
You also don't need these lines in your TotalActivity

```
walkingburned = walkingburned + 0;
runningburned = runningburned + 0;
```

Sorry this was a really long answer but I wanted to explain a few things.

Hope it helps!